# laravel5.2 get entries per week using whereBetween & carbon

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I use whereBetween() to get the results per week. I put them into an array to loop this array in my view and show the records p. week.

For some reason the whereBetween() query seems to be a bit buggy.

my controller code:

```
$dtStart = Carbon::create(2016, 07, 05, 0);

$weeks_passed = $dtStart->diffinWeeks(Carbon::now());

$payouts = [];
DB::enableQueryLog();

for ($i = 0; $i <= $weeks_passed; $i++) {

    if ($i == 0) {

      $payouts = Transaction::where('payed_out',  1)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->whereBetween('updated_at', [$dtStart, $dtStart->addDays(7)])->get();
      dd(DB::getQueryLog());
    }
    else
    { 
      $payouts = Transaction::where('payed_out', 1)->whereIn('user_id', [Auth::user()->id])->whereBetween('updated_at', [$dtStart->addDays($i * 7), $dtStart->addDays(($i + 1) * 7)])->get();
    }
```

Debugging the first query shows for example the last two bindings for the record (the two whereBetween parameters) are both the same (2016-07-12 00:00:00.000000). Any idea where things go wrong?

Comment: I'm making a wild guess here, but I think you should make new instance for each date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**addDays** does not return a new instance of **Carbon** object, it modifies the object it's called on and returns the same object. When you do

```
[$dtStart, $dtStart->addDays(7)]
```

both elements of the array point to the same object, that's why you see the same values in the query.

Replace the array above with:

```
[$dtStart, $dtStart->copy()->addDays(7)]
```

so that two different objects are passed and **addDays** is called on the copy of the original object.